# rem does not respect users setting on smart phones

Tags: css, sass, font-size

I am trying to use rem to respect users setting for font-size:

I added the following first in my css file:

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
```

Then I added font-size as rem to my element.
such as :

```
.header{
font-size: 1.5 rem;
}
```

In desktop and even in simulator it works fine means when I change the font size setting in browser I can see that my page font size changes to reflect the browser settings however in phones such as iphones when I try

1) Go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Larger Text.
2) Tap Larger Accessibility Sizes for bigger font options.
3) Drag the slider to select the font size you want.

I do not see any changes at all. Is there any trick I need to use or is it possible at all?

Comment: I'm going to take a guess at this - you have this problem because REM is not about respecting users settings. It's about being relative to the main HTML DOM setting. If the mobile browser does not add the correct font-size to the DOM, then there is no way of respecting it.

Comment: @CalvT So does it mean that it is out of my hand and it is upto device browser to decide upon that?

Comment: Yes that's right. You have no control over if the browser includes the font size in the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work using `rem` and `-apple-system-body`

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway");
html { 
    /* Must go on the HTML tag to work with rem */
    font: -apple-system-body;
}
p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}


<p>This is some text in my page.</p>
```

More info: http://www.interactiveaccessibility.com/blog/text-resizing-web-pages-ios-using-dynamic-type